# How to change the cell font size in a Plotly-Dash DataTable?

Tags: python, datatable, plotly-dash

How do you change the font size of the information in the cells of a Dash DataTable using Python? It seems like `style_cell` or `style_data` is where I should be able to change the font size but it doesn't have an effect.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict(
    [
        ("Date", ["2015-01-01", "2015-10-24", "2016-05-10", "2017-01-10", "2018-05-10", "2018-08-15"]),
        ("Region", ["Montreal", "Toronto", "New York City", "Miami", "San Francisco", "London"]),
        ("Temperature", [1, -20, 3.512, 4, 10423, -441.2]),
        ("Humidity", [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]),
        ("Pressure", [2, 10924, 3912, -10, 3591.2, 15]),
    ]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(

    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
    style_cell=[
        {
            'if': {'column_id': 'Region'},
            'font_size': '28px',
            'textAlign': 'left'
        }
    ],
    style_cell_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {'column_id': 'Region'},
            'font_size': '28px',
            'textAlign': 'left'
        }
    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```